# how to print directory from ftp server

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem in print the directory from ftp server I'm using Net Commons Apache API

```
FtpClient  ftpclient=new FtpClient();
ftpclient.connect("garbo.uwasa.fi");
System.out.println("this is reply code"+ftpclient.getReplyCode());
```

This last statement give replycode=220

```
 String workingdirectory=ftpclient.printWorkingDirectory();
```

In printdirectory I get null. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your ftp directory doesn't need some sort of authentication?

Comment: Here is a sample of how to connect to ftp directories : http://www.kodejava.org/examples/357.html

Comment: hey aki i resolve this problem. It require authentication after connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FtpClient client=new FtpClient();
clent.connect("www.ftpserver.com");
clent.login("username","password");
String workingdirectory=ftp.printWorkingDirectory();
this working code so u can access ftp server by using this
```